# Sticky Menu breaking on Safari (margin issue?)

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, margin

I have an issue which I've tried to resolve for several hours now.

There is a fixed element on my site for the menu, sticks to the top of the webpage with no margin or spacing above it.

Works great on firefox, chrome, but on Safari about half of the menu is cut off from the top of the page.

Website: uprighthealth.com

Chrome:
[chrome - working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6gyV.png)

Safari:
[safari - broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t3uM.png)

Currently I have the issue patched with a browser specific fix but I know that's not solving the real issue. To see whats happening just disable the 2 browser specific styles under id="nav-container" and id="header" in safari

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

add top/left positions to fixed element:

```
div#nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bogdan! Worked like a charm!